# How to avoid Datasource value from being overriden in multiple expanded Mat-Table rows?

Tags: angular, angular-material

While expanding multiple rows in a Material Mat-Table in which each row fetches data from an API , the dataSource is getting overridden for the already open rows , i.e - the first rows inner data is override by the second row inner data when 2nd row is opened . Similarly if 3rd row is opened all the inner data becomes same .

I tried changing the `dataSource` with `dataSource[i]` based on the index values but that didnt work .

[I have a working stackblitz for the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-wsnkyh?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using element.Id to access datasource array solves the problem. Like,

```
this.usersdataSource[element.Id] = new MatTableDataSource();
```

And you can use the same in template.

Updated the blitz for you. [Updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-kewdq2?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html)